# How to bend or give curve any view in android?

Tags: java, android

1) Is my original view

2) give curve down

3) give curve up

i am looking for best way to bend or give curve in any of view,

[image]

Comment: Extend the `View` and override `onDraw` with your bending code. Good luck with it...

Comment: Better off create your own 9 patch images

Comment: @m0skit0 can you tell me how to do it exactly ? I want my horizontal view to be like 3rd one so the elements will scroll in the bended frame. NEED HELP !

Comment: I already told you. I'm not going to write it for you :) Now it's your turn. Try to do it and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: you didn't quit help @m0skit0... it was obvious you need to create a custom view. the question was how

Comment: @HampelElőd How is explained in the Android tutorials and SDK. This isn't a code factory where you come and ask for other people to code for you. If you show some work, I can help further. If you refuse to do anything, don't expect me to do it for you.

Comment: @m0skit0 then you could at least give the guy a link to a tutorial with this specific problem. And if you know how to do this, then you could write a tutorial about it, and post the link here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
Android library to display a ListView which cells are not rigid but flabby and react to ListView scroll and touch events.
That you  can get your curve code,

https://github.com/jpardogo/FlabbyListView